# Ordinal Not Found ComCtl32.dll C++ on XP

Tags: c++, windows-xp, ordinal

I got this error when c++ program made on win 7 run on xp. Here the error
[support.microsoft.com/kb/260283](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260283)

I got `The ordinal 380 could not be located in the dynamic link library (COMCTL32.DLL)`
. How can I fix that without 
`Copy the Comctl32.dll File from Another Computer` . How can I add that dll direct in my program. Or another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add comctl32.dll directly to you program. It is part of operation system. Each version of Windows has own version of this library. The root of you problem is that you using some WinAPI that is not supported by Windows XP.

You can define minimum supported Windows version with WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT macros. After doing that you will see at compile time some errors that show you what api is not supported by  minimum requred windows version.

You can read more about minimum version requirement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa383745%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Try to rewrite some parts of code without using unsupported functions. This is the only way.